# Keystone JS: local file uploads being auto-renamed

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

Whenever i am uploading file after upload name is getting change to random value? I think it is default function of keystone.How can i stop this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31573836/6271729 check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `originalName: true` to the schema configuration. This gives you both names as a reference.